# Necessary for application to finish launching before 'viewDidAppear' to be called?

Tags: ios, appdelegate, viewdidappear

Simple question... Is it necessary for the application to finish launching before 'viewDidAppear' to be called?

**In more detail...**

I have `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didFinishLaunching", name: UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification, object: nil)` in the `viewDidLoad` of my initial view controller.

I want to know if `viewDidAppear` is ALWAYS going to be called after `didFinishLaunching`?]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need this?

Comment: Yes! I use this in my initial view controller because it is in my app delegates didFinishLaunching method that I initialize Parse. And so, I need to know when that is called so that I can make my API call in that initial view controller. Make sense?

Comment: Now that I think of it, maybe I could just initialize Parse before my API request in that initial view controller. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: You certainly shouldn't tie any app life cycle events to whether you have initialized Parse or not. Why not post your own app specific notification when Parse is initialized and have your view controller listen for that event. Or one of many other possibilities. But you certainly shouldn't worry about the order of app and view controller life cycle method order.

Comment: Oh okay I see, I really appreciate your help. Not sure how to post my own app specific notification for Parse, but I like the sound of that. Do you know any other posts that explain how to do that?

Comment: See the `NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` method.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still curious now, however, as to whether or not `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` MUST be called before a view controller is loaded and visible on-screen.